# CSS3 Animation conflicting with click

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms, perspective

So I have an animation that starts if the input is clicked, it's sort of the Windows 8 animation when you long press or right click.

My JS:

```
$("body").on('click',function(e){
    if($(e.target).closest(".img_list")){
        var inp = $(e.target).closest(".img_list").find("input")[0];
        if(inp.checked){
            $(e.target).closest(".img_list").addClass("clicked tilting");
        }else{
            $(e.target).closest(".img_list").removeClass("clicked tilting");
        }
    }
});
```

And the CSS of the toggled class:

```
@keyframes tilter{
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: perspective(320px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -8deg);
        transform: perspective(320px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -8deg);
    }
    25%{
-webkit-transform: perspective(320px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 8deg);
        transform: perspective(320px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 8deg);        
    }
    50%{
        -webkit-transform: perspective(320px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -8deg);
        transform: perspective(320px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -8deg);
    }
    75%{
        -webkit-transform: perspective(320px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 8deg);
        transform: perspective(320px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 8deg);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform: perspective(320px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -8deg);
        transform: perspective(320px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -8deg);
    }        
}
```

But it's conflicting with my click event, for some reason the target is not there when I click.

It's hard to explain so I wrote a **[fiddle for you here](http://jsfiddle.net/yUUTb/)** if you click like a madman you'll eventually see this happen. It also has my original code which was easier than this, and cleaner.

Can someone explain to me as  to why this is a conflict?

Comment: Are you sure it's your js? Looks to me like the left upper portion doesn't click at all. That would be due to the CSS transform

Comment: Your right! So what would be a clean fix to this. It's not my JS I know that it's the CSS3 Animation (transform/rotate3d), it seems like an odd bug to me really.

Comment: It's quite a common issue with CSS animation. One minute, I'll write up an answer

Comment: @EasyBB your JS code is totally fine. The problem is in the CSS code.

Comment: @King I know lol. Thats why I wrote CSS3 animation conflicting with click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some notes about your CSS in general:

- Only put the prefixes of the vendor inside of the prefixed keyframe animation, meaning only `-webkit-transform` in your `@-webkit-keyframes` etc.
- You can reuse a keyframe by separating the values by a comma, so you can have `0%, 50%, 100% { ... do something ... }` instead of having three separate ones
- Since you're not viewing the back at all, `backface-visibility` is not needed. On the same note, `visible` is the default value so you don't have to state it most of the time
- Avoid `!important`s as they are hard to change later. Always opt for using selector specificity over them
- Always put the unprefixed properties after the prefixed ones, so `-webkit-animation` should come *before* `animation` because you want things to be as standard across browsers as possible
- Try to keep your code clean looking, it really does help later on and also helps others working with you or after you

Now for your actual problem:

The [`perspective`*function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective) is only supported in Webkit browsers. The perspective *function* is the one inside of a `transform`, like so: `-webkit-transform: perspective(n)`

As a result, you should apply perspective by instead **using the perspective *property*** on the parent instead. In this case that would mean the body element, but a more specific parent would generally be better.

Here's a [cleaned up version](http://jsfiddle.net/yUUTb/3/) of your code with it working

As KingKing noted in his [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899637/css3-animation-conflicting-with-click/24899875?noredirect=1#comment38682090_24899875), you can also fix this by applying `perspective(0) rotate3d(0,1,0,0)` on the parent. [Demo of that](http://jsfiddle.net/yUUTb/2/), but it's more preferable to use the more standard `perspective` property.

---

For others looking later, your problem may not be exactly the same. Most CSS rendering issues are caused by the lack of hardware acceleration, which you can force using `transform: translateZ(1px)` (with prefix) or in the future by using the [`will-change`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-will-change-1/) property

Comment: There is another fix by applying a `-webkit-transform:perspective(0) rotate3d(0,1,0,0)` on the parent element (body in this case) here http://jsfiddle.net/yUUTb/2/ , but of course it's better to use `perspective` property. However I think the problem is caused by how the function `perspective` works. In the demo the OP already uses `rotate3d` so the hardware acceleration is already enabled by that, no need more `translateZ(1px)` (and even using `0px` instead of `1px` is OK).

Comment: @KingKing My mention of the `translateZ` was to help other users as that is the most common source of error, though I'm open to changing it if you are against that opinion

Comment: @ZachSaucier you're one of the good ones bud! I always like seeing people even if it's not mentioned to explain and evaluate the code best that it can be. It helps Especially since I've stayed away from these because of the cross browser compat so never took the time to learn them. Thanks again mate, I'm going to try to do what you said.

Comment: Ok after reviewing I see what you have done, and I do like it! It was sketchy because you did `0%,50%,100%` and `25%,50%` so it looked odd, then I realized just a typo. `25%,75%` is what that should be. :) thanks. Plus 1 and Marked as answered!